# How do we allot the secondary CIDR to VPC in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc, cidr

I have a custom VPC with the CIDR block of 192.168.0.0/16. I have a use case where I need more IP's and so I added another CIDR block of range 10.0.0.0/16. Now this range wont work. Technically this should work as it falls in the range of 10.0.0.0/8. Also 172.0.0.0/16 this works. How exactly is this working?

The error shows :
"Failed to add IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16
The CIDR '10.0.0.0/16' is restricted. Use a CIDR from the same private address range as the current VPC CIDR, or use a publicly-routable CIDR. For additional restrictions, see [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#VPC_Sizing%22)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot add 10.0.0.0/16 because It's restricted CIDR for the primary CIDR 192.168.0.0/16. It allows CIDRs in the same Class (A, B, C) and public routable CIDR.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I got it.

Comment: Actually, you can add 2 CIDRs in VPC such as 192.168.0.0/16 and 192.169.0.0/16 but this config won't work in the real case.

Comment: I understand that it is restricted.  But why does this restriction exist?

Comment: The link to the tables is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/configure-your-vpc.html#add-cidr-block-restrictions

Comment: not sure why your link won't show the table, this one does https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-cidr-blocks.html