# AWS VPC CIDR in both 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.0.0/16

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, cidr

I have VPC A with CIDR `10.A.0.0/16` and VPC B with CIDR `10.B.0.0/16`.  I have VPC A and B peered and updated the route tables and from a server in `10.B.0.0/16` can ping a server in `10.A.0.0/16` and vice versa.

The applications on VPC A also use some IPs in the `192.168.0.0/16` range.  Not something I can easily change, but I need to be able to reach `192.168.0.0/16` on VPC A from VPC B.

I've tried adding `192.168.0.0/16` to the route table used for VPC B and setting the target of the peered connection. That does not work, I believe because `192.168.0.0/16` is not in the CIDR block for VPC A.

I'm unable to add `192.168.0.0/16` as a secondary CIDR in VPC A because it is restricted. See [CIDR block association restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#add-cidr-block-restrictions) and [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381126/how-do-we-allot-the-secondary-cidr-to-vpc-in-aws).  I understand it is restricted, but why is it restricted?  RFC1918 doesn't seem to say anything against using more than one of the private address spaces.

I've also tried making a Transit Gateway, attaching both VPCs, and adding a static route to the Transit Gateway Route Table for `192.168.0.0/16` that targets the VPC A attachment.  But still cannot reach that range from within VPC B.

**Is there another way to peer to both `10.0.0.0/8` and `192.168.0.0/16` CIDR blocks on the same VPC?**

##### Updated, background info

The VPCs are used by two different kubernetes clusters.  The older one uses project-calico that uses the default cluster CIDR `192.168.0.0/16` and pod IPs get assigned in that range.  The newer one is an EKS cluster and pod IPs are assigned from the VPC's CIDR range.  During the transition period I've got the two clusters' VPCs peered together.

##### Route Table

The route table for the private subnet for VPC A

```
10.A.0.0/16    local
10.B.0.0/16    pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
0.0.0.0/0      nat-[gateway for cluster A]
```

Route table for the private subnet for VPC B

```
10.B.0.0/16    local
10.A.0.0/16    pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
192.168.0.0/16 pcx-[VPC A - VPC B peering connection]
0.0.0.0/0      nat-[gateway for cluster B]
```

This does not work, of course, because `192.168.0.0/16` is not in VPC A's CIDR block, nor can it be added.

Comment: How does your application use IPs in the `192.168.0.0/16` range, if that range hasn't been added as a secondary CIDR block in the VPC? That should be impossible.

Comment: It's an older k8s cluster that uses project Calico and the cluster CIDR defaults to `192.168.0.0/16` so pod IPs get assigned from that range.  The newer one is an EKS cluster that assigns pod IPs in the VPC's CIDR range.

Comment: I don't know anything about project Calico, but if it is using IPs in a range that aren't part of the VPC CIDR block, then they aren't routable within the VPC.

Comment: No one on my team knows anything about project Calico either! But the pods do get assigned those IP addresses and I can ping a VPC A pod with IP address in `192.168.0.0/16` range from a worker node in the same cluster/VPC but not from the newer cluster/VPC B.  Pods in VPC A can reach pods in both VPCs but pods in VPC B can only reach fellow VPC B pods.

Comment: @MarkB wouldn't that make them routable within the VPC currently?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea how that's working to be honest. You might try including more information like your routing table details. You might also try asking over at ServerFault, as this seems like more of an advanced networking question than a programming question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236745/discussion-between-gangstead-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 2):

Calico creates an overlay network using the specified cluster CIDR (192.168.x.x) on top of VPC (A) CIDR, so pods/services in this k8s cluster can communicate. The overlay network routing information is neither expose nor usable for AWS route table. This is different from k8s cluster running in VPC (B) which uses VPC CNI that leverage on the VPC CIDR as the cluster CIDR.

Calico [BGP Peering](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/bgp) offers a way here but it is not going to be an easy route for this case.

> Calico nodes can exchange routing information over BGP to enable
> reachability for Calico networked workloads (Kubernetes pods or
> OpenStack VMs).

If you must achieve pod to pod communication in different k8s clusters and networks but not via Ingress/LB, migrate one of the k8s cluster CNI to be the same as the other so you can fully leverage on their unique peering capabilities.